# GUI Design with HTML5 & CSS3 in eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, html, css, cordova

I am using eclipse kepler version for developing Android native applications with Phonegap. I have also added **JSDT jQuery** plugin which is helping me for jQuery intellisense and code highlighting. But I want the same for my HTML5 and Css3 files, So that I can work on its GUI in that platform.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Web Tools Platform(WTP) in Eclipse Kepler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917908/how-to-add-web-tools-platformwtp-in-eclipse-kepler)

Answer (score 1):

See this [link](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/). 
All you need is Web Tools Platform plugin installed in your Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: Could you please help me how to download this plugin and install in my eclipse kepler

Comment: Houw should I help you ? Say !?

Comment: I know to install a plugin by using the the name and Location in Help>new Software-Add. Is there any URL exist to install this WTP plugin