# How to add Web Tools Platform(WTP) in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-wtp

I installed `Eclipse Kepler` in my system. so far I developed `J2SE` Applications. Now I want to develop `J2EE` Application.So I need to add `WTP` in my eclipse.

I tried to add `WTP` in already existing eclipse.For this

I open Install Dialog in the following way.and mention `Name and Location` values

```
 Help-->Install New Software-->Add
```

[image]

after that, I click on

```
 Ok-->Select All-->Next-->Next-->
```

I got error like this.

[image]

Why I am getting error?How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do u select everything in the WTP..can't you select only the things which you want. For example uncheck the 'Patch feature for Tests" while installing and intall

Comment: @saurav I tried like that. Installation was done successfully,but It's not allowing me to setting `Apache Tomcat` as a runtime target.also it's not showing `Dynamic Web Project` under `Web` folder.It showing `Static Web Project` under `Web` folder.

Answer (score 10):

Use the Kepler site.  The URL you're using is not supposed to be used any more (the timestamps you see are very old).  http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and did this:

- Click "Help" > "Install new software"
- In "Work with", paste: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler
- In "Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development", check:

  - Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
  - Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools
  - Eclipse Web Developer Tools
  - Eclipse XML Editors and Tools
- Finally, click "Next" to install the new software and "Dynamic Web Project" will be available.

Comment: Could you please edit the steps provide them line by line for clear understanding for all users

Answer (score 2):

It's happened because you have already installed this package as i understand. So you just need to uncheck "Path feature for tests" at previous window.

p.s.: sorry for my english, i'm from Ukraine and i study english now.